# How to make a div take no horizontal space

Tags: html, css

I have a div on the top.

```
< div class="ad-top">
    < img class="adtop" src="images.jpg" height="90" width="728"/>
< /div>
```

I have tried this code below

```
.ad-top{
padding: 0;
height: 90px;
width: 728px;
margin:0px 100px 0px 100px;
border: 1px solid black;
float: left;
}
```

but it still takes horizontal space to the right and pushes the advertisement on the right below. How to fix it?

This is the code for advertisement on the right.

```
div.ad-right{
height: 600px;
width: 300px;
margin-right: 50px;
float: right;
}
```

And this is the code for the section. (Note = the divs for advertisements are not children of the section.)

```
section{
    padding-left: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}

section div{
    width: 900px;
}

section div p{
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Can you make fiddle or SO snippet?

Comment: Can we have you code in fiddle.

Comment: @Kemal  just put your code with jsffidle and many suggestion and your solutions will be here for you dude but for that you need to create running demo of your code

Comment: Im new to html and css. Can someone guide me through making this fiddle thing?

Comment: @Kemal, you can go to the [jsfiddle site](http://jsfiddle.net/) (there are other sites out there) and enter your html and css code (and javascript if you're using any) to create a run-able sample. When you save it the URL will change and you can share it. If you're using any images on your local machine though you'll have to update them.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle. It looks different than normal however. Images updated as well. https://jsfiddle.net/nyz1yjtn/

Comment: Isn't the problem that your ad-right div comes after the content? If you order it ad-top, ad-right, content then it should work.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: That's good - I already added an answer below with a bit more detail. This may cause problems on smaller screens (i.e. phones) as the ad will appear before the content. It may be worth adding an @media {} section to the css that makes the ad invisible below a certain resolution.

Comment: Sorry but I'm pretty new to this. Where do add that and write what exactly?

Comment: Also can you explain how did the order actually affect this? I can't seem to understand why.

Comment: I can't understand what exactly you want, but i think you should try this:

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

Hi now **remove** `float` `left` to your **class** `.ad-top` and **add** `display:inline-block;` and `vertical-align:top;` and **define** your  `img` tag `vertical-align:top` **as like this** .

```
.ad-top{
float:none;
border: solid 1px black;
display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;
}
.ad-top img{
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**Demo code is**

```css
div.ad-right{
height: 600px;
width: 300px;
margin-right: 50px;
float: right;
}.ad-top{
padding: 0;
height: 90px;
width: 728px;
margin:0px 100px 0px 100px;
border: solid 1px black;
display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;
}
.ad-top img{
    vertical-align:top;
}section{
    padding-left: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}

section div{
    width: 900px;
}

section div p{
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ad-top">
    <img class="adtop" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/9b4f9deed7c1533d605bc3efb42e3604?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" height="90" width="728"/>
</div>
```

Comment: This code completely lacks any explanation and reads like a game of spot-the-difference, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I copy pasted your demo code and replaced the stuff but as the top image stil ltakes all the horizontal space possible to the right, the ad-right is pushed downwards. Still needs a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Add parent div like wrapper or container which contain static width that include both ads width including margins and also give margin: 0 auto; for the parent div.

```
<div style="margin:0 auto;width:1278px; ">

<div class="ad-top"></div>
<div class="ad-right"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle. It looks different than normal however. Images updated as well. jsfiddle.net/nyz1yjtn

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that your problem is the order of your elements. Because your "ad-right" div comes after the content section, it begins at the same height.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/4cynwzyc/1/embedded/result/) is an updated version where I have changed the order of the elements.

In summary, it is like this now:

```
<div class="ad-top">
        <img class="adtop" src="http://dummyimage.com/728%20x%2090" height="90" width="728" />
</div>
<div class="ad-right">
    <img class="adbig" src="http://dummyimage.com/300%20x%20600" height="600" width="300" />
</div>
<section><!--content--></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update/add below css code:

```
.middle-container{
    margin:0 auto; width:1132px;
}
.ad-top {
    padding: 0;
    height: 90px;
    width: 728px;
    margin:0px 100px 0px 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
div.ad-right {
    height: 600px;
    width: 300px;
    float: right;
}
section {
    padding-left: 50px;
}
section div {
    width: 100%;
}
```

And follow below html structure in your code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="header"></div>

<div class="middle-container">

<div class="ad-top"></div>
<div class="ad-right"></div>
<section></section>

<footer></footer>

</div>

</div>
```